# WPF UI control move position via data binding

Tags: wpf

Please refer to the Model,ViewModel and View below.
 The Textblock control on the view is not getting moved/updated to new position on the screen once i have set the value of the databinding property in the corresponding ViewModel.

Model:

```
  private int _Text_1_Left;
  public int Text_1_Left
     {
         get { return _Text_1_Left; }
         set
         {
             if (_Text_1_Left != value)
             {
                 _Text_1_Left = value;

             }
         }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private int _Text_1_Left = 50;
     public int Text_1_Left
         {
             get { return _Text_1_Left; }
             set
             {
                 if (_Text_1_Left != value)
                 {
                     _Text_1_Left = value;
                     RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Text_1_Left");
                 }
             }
         }
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string Property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
            }
    }

}
```

View(XAML):

```
  <canvas>
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="{Binding ObjMyVM.Text_1_Left,Mode=OneWay}" Canvas.Top="10" />
 </canvas>
```

View(Xaml.cs)
I am setting the DataBinding property in code behind of View.

```
 public form_load()
 {
    MyViewModel objMyVM=new MyViewModel()
    this.DataContext=objMyVM;
 }

 private void cmdMoveLeft_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
         {
             double Left;
             TextBlock lbl_curr_selected;
             lbl_curr_selected = Button_Text_1;

             if (lbl_curr_selected != null)
             {
                 Left = CurrentRec.Text_1_Left;
                 Left = Left <= 0 ? 0 : Left - 5;
                 ObjMyVM.Text_1_Left =int.Parse(Left.ToString()) ;

         }
         }
```

No error but textblock is supposed to move left by 5,which it is currently not doing.
  Please show me how to move the position of a control element on the UI by changing the binding from code-behind.

Comment: Where is `ObjMyVM` defined? It must be the same view model instance as the one assigned to the `DataContext` property. Besides what has been said in the answer, try setting `((MyViewModel)DataContext).Text_1_Left = ...`.

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=OneWay` on the Binding is redundant. The `Canvas.Left` property binds one-way be default.

Comment: ObjMyVM is defined in public scope of the View's code behind

Answer (score 0):

As you have set the data context to the object your binding should just be:

```
Canvas.Left="{Binding Text_1_Left,Mode=OneWay}"
```

Check the console output for the error.

Comment: Showing nuthin in console :-(.

Comment: What about changing the binding?

Comment: As above, removing `ObjMyVM.` from your original